# Java Compare single char to char array

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, char

I need to compare single char to char array and see if array has that char.

My current code looks like this:

```
public boolean isThereChar(char[] chaArray, String chr){
    boolean bool = false;
    for(int i=0; i < chaArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(chr.equals(chaArray[i])){
                    bool = true;
                }
            }
            return bool;
}
```

**Edit Notes:**

Really sorry for being confusing! I am just a Java Beginner =/
Basically I am writing small Hangman game with GUI.
My program reads off text file and randomly chooses word which player has to guess, then prints it out in hidden manner like this: _ _ _ _ _ 
In this case I want player to input character or string (person can guess either whole word or just one letter)
Then I want my program to take that letter or string and compare to my hidden word

Following code chooses word and hides it:

```
public String pickWord(){
    String guessWord = (wordsList[new Random().nextInt(wordsList.length)]);
    return guessWord.toLowerCase();
}

//Hides picked word
public char[] setWord(){
    char[] word = new char[pickWord().length() * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i+=2) {
        word[i] = '_';
        word[i + 1] = ' ';
    }
    return word;
}
```

Then person input his character which he guesses to program with following code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if (action == "Guess Letter"){
        inputChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter (a-z)");
        if (inputChar.length() > 1){
            GuessedLetters glr = new GuessedLetters(inputChar);
            glr.setInString(inputChar);
            //For testing purposes
            System.out.println("This is String: " +glr.getInString());              
        }else{
        GuessedLetters glr = new GuessedLetters(inputChar);
        glr.setInChar(inputChar);
        //For testing purposes
        System.out.println("This is Char: " +glr.getInChar());
        }
    }
```

Lastly I want to take that character which was inputted and compare to my array of chars which is my hidden word:

```
public boolean isThereChar(char[] array, String str){
    return isThereChar(array, str.charAt(0));
}

public boolean isThereChar(char[] array, char c){
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] == c) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to check what does my code returns (true or false), but I keep failing at doing so.
(Right now I am trying to call method in my main class to check it, if you can give me tips how to do it otherwise please let me know.)

Comment: but you are comparing single string. Not a single char.

Comment: And function returns string. Not a char array

Comment: please provide more code, this method doesn't provide enough for NPE

Comment: Can you post some code where you use `isThereChar()`?

Comment: And you are comparing against a whole of array. Not element-wise

Comment: its a string of one character so I can use chr.toCharArray and then back chr.toString, you think it might be problem?

Comment: @irrelephant currently I am just building this method, but basically here I am checking if my char array consists of that letter, if it does then I will reveal it in the game (which yes, it should be bool, let me fix it there)

Comment: please post Output window having exception

Comment: To print what the method returns (true or false): `System.out.println(isThereChar(array, chr) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed");`

Comment: I want to initialize isThereChar(vars); method once I pass them to program. Here I pastebin bits of codes which are relevant pastebin.com/VbiWwyh7 and tried to explain it in comments

Comment: Wow, that's a huge edit. Right after `System.out.println("This is Char: " +glr.getInChar());`, try putting `System.out.println(isThereChar({replace this with your char array}, glr.getInChar() + "") ? "Succeeded" : "Failed");`

Comment: Ok, it compromises with my code which generates random word here i pasted error http://pastebin.com/3tCmbN5j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I got what you need :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if (action == "Guess Letter"){
        inputChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter (a-z)");
        if (inputChar.length() > 1){ //User input is a string here, right?
            GuessedLetters glr = new GuessedLetters(inputChar);
            glr.setInString(inputChar);
            System.out.println(wordToGuess.contains(glr.getInString())); //This will print true if wordToGuess is equal to glr.getInString() or if it just contains it
            //For testing purposes
            System.out.println("This is String: " +glr.getInString());              
        }else{ //Here the user gave us just a character, so we've got to know if this character is contained in the word, right?
        GuessedLetters glr = new GuessedLetters(inputChar);
        glr.setInChar(inputChar);
        System.out.println(wordToGuess.contains(glr.getInChar()); //This will print true if your char is in the wordToGuess string
        //For testing purposes
        System.out.println("This is Char: " +glr.getInChar());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe u got any idea how to check what it returns? trying to print it out to make sure answer is correct, but it just gives me nullpointer exceptions

Comment: You need to know what? The index of the found character? Where does it give a NPE? Have you checked that your `char[] array` isn't null?

Comment: Yeah I print it once I create it. I think I just dont know how to check value that this method returns. Any ideas?

Comment: I still don't get what you need. I'm gonna edit my answer with an example, to see if I can help you

Comment: Basically I want this method to check if char which was inputted by used is in my char array. If it is return true if it is not - false.
Also I want to print out weather it is true or false for testing purposes. And I got stuck on that printing part.

Comment: I've just tested the example that's in my answer and it works. It correctly prints false and then true. Check it out

Comment: Yeah, thanks, very useful example let me see what I can do with my code

Comment: It initializes as soon as I launch my app, but I want it to initialize once I pass variable to it...

Comment: What do you want to initialize once you pass a variable to it?

Comment: I want to initialize isThereChar(vars); method once I pass them to program. Here I pastebin bits of codes which are relevant http://pastebin.com/VbiWwyh7 and tried to explain it in comments

Comment: I've used the static keyword because it was needed in my example. You don't need it in your code. I need to see where do you need to call the `isThereChar()` method

Comment: Sorry, yeah I dont need it. I am calling it in my main method (for testing purposes, to check weather it shows correct value.. I have feeling it is my mistake to do so)

Comment: Seems like you have some problem with java. If you're calling them DIRECTLY in your main method, than you will need the static keyword. If you've got to call them from a method who's not static, you don't need it. Can you please edit your question and tell us what you have got to do and what you've done until now? Post the code of your class.

Comment: Ok i edited trying to make is as clear as possible =/ I am just a beginner at java, kinda hard to write first programs... Sorry

Comment: It seems like when I try to compare it, it doest like my random word generator i pasted both classes: GuessedLetters and WordsList (Random word is picked in WordsList class) http://pastebin.com/wWD1CZcC
also described error I get: http://pastebin.com/3tCmbN5j

Comment: We should avoid long discussions here ...Anyway, have you tried the code that I wrote? Does it print true/false when you input a char/string ? If not, does it print the `System.out.println("This is String: " +glr.getInString());` line?

Answer (score 5):

I would use: `Chars.contains(array, chr);` with [Guava Chars](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html)

Answer (score 3):

The NullPointerException is happening because either `chaArray` or `chr` is `null` when you call the method.  (*And if not, then the NullPointerException is occurring somewhere else!!*)

The other problem with your code is this line:

```
  if (chr.equals(chaArray[i])) {
```

Since `chr` is actually a String, what is going to happen here is that the value of `chaArray[i]` will be auto-boxed as a `Character` object, and then passed as an argument to `String.equals(Object)`.  But the `String.equals(Object)` will return `false` unless its argument is a `String` ... so your code wouldn't find the character anyway.

You need to either compare the character like this:

```
  if (chr.charAt(0) == chaArray[i]) {
```

or declare `chr` to be a `char` and compare it as:

```
  if (chr == chaArray[i]) {
```

Comment: NullPointerException occurs only when I try to print boolean value to check if it is correct.

Comment: So the NPE is not occuring in the code above ... like I said.  If you want us to explain the NPE, you will need to post the code that throws it.

Comment: Any ideas how to check what value it gives? Seems like I just checking it incorrectly.

Comment: Unless you show us the code and the stacktrace, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

`String chr` might be null causing `NullPointerException`.

Use `char chr` instead of `String`.

```
public boolean isThereChar(char[] chaArray, char chr){
    boolean bool = false;
    for(int i=0; i < chaArray.length; i++) {
        if(chr==chaArray[i])){
             bool = true;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the character from the parameter passed in, or pass in a char e.g.

```
chr[0]
```

or

```
public String isThereChar(char[] chaArray, char chr){
    for(int i=0; i < chaArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(chr.equals(chaArray[i])){
                    return chr;
                }
            }
            return "Guess Again";
}
```

Comment: Since this is Java, you'd want to use `chr.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean  isThereChar(char[] chaArray, char chr){        
for(int i=0; i < chaArray.length; i++)
        {
            if((chaArray[i]==chr)){
                return true;   // means Character exist in the Character array
            }
        }
        return false;  //// means Character does not exist in the Character array
}
```